# Convert date to string using default user locale in jPlaton

Tags: string, date, jplaton

I am trying to convert a date variable to a string in Platonscript.
The thing is that i want the convert it using the default local for the current user.

```
@str = (ASDATE:dd/MM/yyyy) @dat
```

I use this but the date pattern is standard. Is there something like

```
@str = (ASDATE:default) @dat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ASDATE without specifying a format. This will give you the (JAVA) DEFAULT date format for your user's locale.

```
@str = (ASDATE) @dat
```

Other predefined Java Date Formats are also available and take into account the user's locale such as:

DEFAULT
SHORT
MEDIUM
LONG
FULL

e.g.

```
@str = (ASDATE:SHORT) @dat
```